# Query with same field multiple times

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables:

**Persons Struct**: id, name and number

**Category Struct**: id, name

**Costs Struct**: id, person_id, cat_id, supplier, price

I need a mysql query that list:

```
Person | Number | Category.name 1| Category.name 2|......| Category.name 9 |
JOE    | 3322   | $ 123.99       | $ 245.99       | .... |  $ 44,99        |
MEL    | 3322   | $ 333.99       | $ 775.99       | .... |  $ 91,99        |
JACK   | 3322   | $ 443.99       | $ 885.99       | .... |  $ 82,99        |
```

The Column `Category.name` is provided by Category Table

The value of this field is the `SUM()` of this category in Costs table

Comment: Here's an example that'll help you write it on your on. http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlleftjoin.php

Comment: Is the max number of categories set at 9, or is it effectively unlimited

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: If you're trying to turn rows in the `Category` table into columns in the result, that's called a "pivot". MySQL doesn't have built-in support for this. If you search SO for "mysql pivot" you will find many similar questions, see the answers there.

Comment: exactly that. uhmm i will search about...